# The sheet music of Morning Mood

Tags: beginner, formatting, audio, music, lilypond

While learning to play the [keyboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_keyboard), I find it helpful to write down the score of the pieces I play, regardless of whether a score already exists.

The code is written using [Frescobaldi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frescobaldi_%28software%29) as IDE and using [LilyPond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LilyPond) ([docs](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/notation/index)) as format and engraving tool under the hood. The music is engraved to PDF and a MIDI file is generated.

Writing music in LilyPond is somewhat similar to writing a book in LaTeX.

I want to share one of the easier pieces. A shortened, simplified piano version of Morning Mood (Morgenstemning) by Edvard Grieg. Specifically, it's a 1:1 translation of the version provided by [Flowkey](https://www.flowkey.com/en) (no affiliation).

---

#### Morning Mood - Edvard Grieg.ly

```
\version "2.18.2"
\language "english"

\header {
  title = "Morning Mood"
  % Morgenstemning Suite No. 1, Op. 46 (Peer Gynt)
  composer = "Edvard Grieg"
  tagline = \markup {
    Engraved at
    \simple #(strftime "%Y-%m-%d" (localtime (current-time)))
    with \with-url #"http://lilypond.org/"
    \line { LilyPond \simple #(lilypond-version) (http://lilypond.org/) }
  }
}

topNotes =
\relative c'' {
  \time 6/8
  \clef treble
  \key c \major
  \override Score.BarNumber.break-visibility = ##(#f #t #t)
    g8 e d c d e g e d c d16 e d e g8 e g a e a g e d c4.
    g'8 e d c d e g e d c d16 e d e g8 e g a e a b gs fs e4.
    b'8 gs fs e fs gs b gs fs e fs16 gs fs gs b8 gs b c gs c d b a g4.
    g8 e d c d e g e d c d16 e d e g4. a4. <e c'>2.
    
}

bottomNotes =
\relative c {
  \time 6/8
  \clef bass
  \key c \major
    <c e g>2. <c e g> <c e g>4. <c e a>4. <c e g>4. g'8 e d
    <c e g>2. <c e g> <c e g>4. <c e a>4. <e gs b>4. b'8 gs fs
    <e gs b>2. <e gs b>2. <e gs b>4. <c' gs e>4. <g b d>4 . d'8 b a
    <c, e g>4. <c e a>4.  <c e g>4. <c e a>4. <c e g>4. <c f a>4. <c e g>2.
    
}

\score {
  <<
    \new Staff \with {
    instrumentName = "Piano"
    midiInstrument = "acoustic grand"
  } { \topNotes }
    \new Staff \with {
    instrumentName = "Piano"
    midiInstrument = "acoustic grand"
  } { \bottomNotes }
  >>
  \layout {}
  \midi {}
}
```

---

Partial screenshot of the resulting PDF:

[image: Morning Mood - Edvard Grieg]

Audio: [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20190803053720/https://instaud.io/1dGe)

*Note:* the chords should be sustained longer than can be heard in the provided audio, an unfortunate conversion artefact unrelated to the code written.

Thoughts of interest:

- I'd expect the `tagline` has to be declared in the footer, but so far every example I've seen declares it in the header. So that's where I put it. Regardless of where you declare it though, it gets placed at the bottom of the page anyway.
- There's code duplication between the top staff and bottom staff. Both have a [MIDI instrument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_MIDI#Program_change_events) assigned, in this case the same instrument. Can I extract this declaration to a variable? In this case it doesn't matter much, except it looks stupid. But on a 4-hand piece it would look extra stupid. Perhaps this can be fixed by grouping staves, but so far I haven't figured it out.
- I'm writing in [relative mode](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.19/Documentation/learning/simple-notation). At times, this makes the notation look odd. Where you'd expect 2 parts to look exactly alike in the code, it's possible they won't if the note before it was different. While entering notes is relatively easy this way, it may be a bad idea to continue this route.
- I'm using `\override Score.BarNumber.break-visibility = ##(#f #t #t)` to show measure numbers at the beginning of every measure and after every staff break (I don't need them at the end of the staff, hence the first parameter is #f false). If I understand correctly, this can only be declared in a part included by the score but not at the score itself. So I put it in the `topNotes`. Smells like it would be better to use a separate variable to store score modifiers like that, but I don't know how to do that in an obvious and neat manner.
- I put a line break at every 4 measures because the part happened to be a multiple of 4 (16 measures) and that was just about the amount I could fit on my screen without side-scrolling.

Basically, it works like a charm, the result looks like a charm, but the code itself could use some serious clean-up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a lot of boilerplate in LilyPond to put all the parts together.  In your case, you used:

> ```
> \score {
>   <<
>     \new Staff \with {
>     instrumentName = "Piano"
>     midiInstrument = "acoustic grand"
>   } { \topNotes }
>     \new Staff \with {
>     instrumentName = "Piano"
>     midiInstrument = "acoustic grand"
>   } { \bottomNotes }
>   >>
>   …
> }
> ```

… which is not quite right.  I recommend:

```
global = {
  \time 6/8
  \key c \major
}

\score {
  \new PianoStaff <<
    \set PianoStaff.instrumentName = #"Piano"
    \new Staff = "upper" {
      \global
      \clef treble
      \rhNotes
    }
    \new Staff = "lower" {
      \global
      \clef bass
      \lhNotes
    }
  >>
  \layout {}
  \midi {}
}
```

This has three consequences:

- The [`\PianoStaff`](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/learning/solo-piano) directive creates a curly brace that binds the two staves together, indicating that they are to be played on a single instrument.

  Note that ["acoustic grand" is the default MIDI instrument anyway](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/notation/midi-instruments), so I didn't bother to specify it.
- Defining `global` parameters reduces duplication.
- In my opinion, in this case, the clef would be better specified as a property of the staff, rather than as a property of the notes.  (However, in more advanced music, where the clef can change in the middle of a piece, I would specify the clefs among the notes, as you did.)

---

In my opinion, showing every single bar number is annoying overkill:

> ```
> \override Score.BarNumber.break-visibility = ##(#f #t #t)
> ```

Better to declutter the score so that you can put more useful numbers there such as [fingering](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/learning/articulation-and-dynamics#fingerings).

Assuming that you did want to use the `\override` directive, it would be better to put it in the `global` variable that I introduced above.

---

It is very good practice to include all [bar checks](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/notation/bars#bar-and-bar-number-checks) to help you catch rhythm mistakes, and to make the code easier to read:

```
g8 e d c d e | g e d c d16 e d e | g8 e g a e a | g e d c4. |
```

Assuming that this is the entire piece rather than an excerpt, you should end it with a double bar line:

```
g8 e d c d e | g e d c d16 e d e | g4. a4. | <e c'>2. \bar "|."
```

---

Writing the pitches in relative mode is fine.  Absolute mode would be a pain.

Comment: Honestly, the extra bar numbers helped while inserting the score. Now it's complete, you're right. It's clutter that should be replaced by more important remarks. Overall a good answer, thanks for enlightening me.